# How to dynamically update ListView while fetching data asynchronously?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to figure out the best way to update a `ListView.builder()` while I'm fetching a list of data. Essentially, I am downloading data in batches -- let's say a group of 10 images at a time -- and displaying them in a `ListView.builder` after the future completes, with an indicator below it to signify that we're still fetching data. And do this until everything is fetched.

What's the best way of going about this?

Example code of what I have:

```dart
void _fetchImages() async {
  // Fetch images
  for (...) {
    final results = await Future.wait[imageFutures];
    
    // update list here
    imageList.addAll(results); // let's say data comes back in correct format
    setState((){});
  }  
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _fetchImages();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(...);
}
```

Comment: you may like Stream with StreamBuilder

Comment: @yeasin-sheikh I've tried using StreamBuilder. Can I call `setState` inside my stream function? I have `_fetchImages` before as a stream and I didn't know what to return, just update my list of images like what you see. Should I be returning the list from the stream instead?

Comment: You don't need to call setState if you return list from stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `List` from `Stream` then you can use `StreamBuilder`.

```
    return StreamBuilder<List<MyImage>>(
      stream: dataStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<MyImage>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                ...
          );
        }
        return SomeWidget(
         ...
        );
      },
    );
```